# Error "System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null." when returning connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to get the connection string from my app.config in another class but I keep getting the error in the title, here's the part where I'm trying to return the connection string from my app.config:

```
public static string CnnString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
```

And here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="GreaterWinner" value="1"/>
        <add key="ApplicationEmail" value="X@gmail.com"/>
        <add key="ApplicationDisplayName" value="Gym Tournament"/>
     </appSettings>
    <ConnectionStrings>
        <add name="Tournament" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=Tournament;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </ConnectionStrings>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
                         port="X"
                         userName="X"
                         password="X"
                         enableSsl="true"
                    />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Feel like the first place to look is what is the value of your 'name' parameter. Are you certain it's "Tournament" because I can't see it.

Comment: If your curious on why you're getting the exact error, the 'ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name]' part is null, therefore calling .ConnectionString on 'null' will get you this error, for some reason it can't find the connection string you're looking for.

Comment: The name of that section is `connectionStrings`, not `ConnectionStrings` -- case matters.